Manually unwrapping JSON without codeable - Swift
I am trying to manually unwrap JSON without the use of codeable. I can get the top level to display but I can not get the beneficiary address to display. I know it's something in my model. I was hoping someone can take a look at my code.
JSON Example

My Model
class Beneficiary {
    
    private struct JSONConstants {
        static let lastName = "lastName"
        static let firstName = "firstName"
        static let designationCode = "designationCode"
        static let beneType = "beneType"
        static let ssn = "socialSecurityNumber"
        static let dob = "dateOfBirth"
        static let middleName = "middleName"
        static let phoneNumber = "phoneNumber"
        static let beneficiaryAddress = "beneficiaryAddress"
    }
    
    let beneficiaryLastName: String
    let beneficiaryFirstName: String
    let beneficiaryDesignationCode: String
    let beneficiaryType: String
    let beneficiarySSN: String
    let beneficiaryDOB: String
    let beneficiaryMiddleName: String
    let beneficiaryPhoneNumber: String
    let beneficiaryAddress: BeneficiaryAddress
    
    init(beneficiaryLastName: String, beneficiaryFirstName: String, beneficiaryDesignationCode: String, beneficiaryType: String, beneficiarySSN: String, beneficiaryDOB: String, beneficiaryMiddleName: String, beneficiaryPhoneNumber: String, beneficiaryAddress: BeneficiaryAddress) {
        
        self.beneficiaryLastName = beneficiaryLastName
        self.beneficiaryFirstName = beneficiaryFirstName
        self.beneficiaryDesignationCode = beneficiaryDesignationCode
        self.beneficiaryType = beneficiaryType
        self.beneficiarySSN = beneficiarySSN
        self.beneficiaryDOB = beneficiaryDOB
        self.beneficiaryMiddleName = beneficiaryMiddleName
        self.beneficiaryPhoneNumber = beneficiaryPhoneNumber
        self.beneficiaryAddress = beneficiaryAddress
    }
    
    ///Convenience Init used to create a Beneficiary object with a json object
    convenience init(json: [String: AnyObject]) {
        
        let beneficiaryLastName = json[JSONConstants.lastName] as? String ?? ""
        let beneficiaryFirstName = json[JSONConstants.firstName] as? String ?? ""
        let beneficiaryDesignationCode = json[JSONConstants.designationCode] as? String ?? ""
        let beneficiaryType = json[JSONConstants.beneType] as? String ?? ""
        let beneficiarySSN = json[JSONConstants.ssn] as? String ?? ""
        let beneficiaryDOB = json[JSONConstants.dob] as? String ?? ""
        let beneficiaryMiddleName = json[JSONConstants.middleName] as? String ?? ""
        let beneficiaryPhoneNumber = json[JSONConstants.phoneNumber] as? String ?? ""
        let beneficiaryAddress = json[JSONConstants.beneficiaryAddress] as? BeneficiaryAddress ?? BeneficiaryAddress(beneficiaryAddressOne: "Unavailable", beneficiaryAddressTwo: "Unavailable", beneficiaryCity: "Unavailable", beneficiaryZipCode: "Unavailable", beneficiaryStateCode: "Unavailable", beneficiaryCountry: "Unavailable")
        
        self.init(beneficiaryLastName: beneficiaryLastName, beneficiaryFirstName: beneficiaryFirstName, beneficiaryDesignationCode: beneficiaryDesignationCode, beneficiaryType: beneficiaryType, beneficiarySSN: beneficiarySSN, beneficiaryDOB: beneficiaryDOB, beneficiaryMiddleName: beneficiaryMiddleName, beneficiaryPhoneNumber: beneficiaryPhoneNumber, beneficiaryAddress: beneficiaryAddress)
    }
    
    /**
    helper function used to transform self into JSON, used for local persistence.

    - returns: dictionary that we can use to serialize later
     
    */
    func convertSelfToJSON() -> [String:Any] {
        return [
            JSONConstants.lastName: beneficiaryLastName,
            JSONConstants.firstName: beneficiaryFirstName,
            JSONConstants.designationCode: beneficiaryDesignationCode,
            JSONConstants.beneType: beneficiaryType,
            JSONConstants.ssn: beneficiarySSN,
            JSONConstants.dob: beneficiaryDOB,
            JSONConstants.middleName: beneficiaryMiddleName,
            JSONConstants.phoneNumber: beneficiaryPhoneNumber,
            JSONConstants.beneficiaryAddress: beneficiaryAddress
        ]
    }
}

//MARK: - Beneficiary Address Level Two
/**
Second level beneficiary data from JSON
*/
class BeneficiaryAddress {
    
    private struct JSONConstants {
        static let addressLineOne = "firstLineMailing"
        static let addressLineTwo = "scndLineMailing"
        static let city = "city"
        static let zipCode = "zipCode"
        static let stateCode = "stateCode"
        static let country = "oountry"
    }
    
    let beneficiaryAddressOne: String
    let beneficiaryAddressTwo: String // Handle this properly as the result is null
    let beneficiaryCity: String
    let beneficiaryZipCode: String
    let beneficiaryStateCode: String
    let beneficiaryCountry: String
    
    init(beneficiaryAddressOne: String, beneficiaryAddressTwo: String, beneficiaryCity: String, beneficiaryZipCode: String, beneficiaryStateCode: String, beneficiaryCountry: String) {
        
        self.beneficiaryAddressOne = beneficiaryAddressOne
        self.beneficiaryAddressTwo = beneficiaryAddressTwo
        self.beneficiaryCity = beneficiaryCity
        self.beneficiaryZipCode = beneficiaryZipCode
        self.beneficiaryStateCode = beneficiaryStateCode
        self.beneficiaryCountry = beneficiaryCountry
    }
    
    ///Convenience Init used to create a Beneficiary object with a json object
    convenience init(json: [String: AnyObject]) {
        
        let beneficiaryAddressOne = json[JSONConstants.addressLineOne] as? String ?? ""
        let beneficiaryAddressTwo = json[JSONConstants.addressLineTwo] as? String ?? ""
        let beneficiaryCity = json[JSONConstants.city] as? String ?? ""
        let beneficiaryZipCode = json[JSONConstants.zipCode] as? String ?? ""
        let beneficiaryStateCode = json[JSONConstants.stateCode] as? String ?? ""
        let beneficiaryCountry = json[JSONConstants.country] as? String ?? ""
        
        self.init(beneficiaryAddressOne: beneficiaryAddressOne, beneficiaryAddressTwo: beneficiaryAddressTwo, beneficiaryCity: beneficiaryCity, beneficiaryZipCode: beneficiaryZipCode, beneficiaryStateCode: beneficiaryStateCode, beneficiaryCountry: beneficiaryCountry)
    }
    
    /**
    helper function used to transform self into JSON, used for local persistence.

    - returns: dictionary that we can use to serialize later
     
    */
    func convertSelfToJSON() -> [String: Any] {
        return [
            JSONConstants.addressLineOne: beneficiaryAddressOne,
            JSONConstants.addressLineTwo: beneficiaryAddressTwo,
            JSONConstants.city: beneficiaryCity,
            JSONConstants.zipCode: beneficiaryZipCode,
            JSONConstants.stateCode: beneficiaryStateCode,
            JSONConstants.country: beneficiaryCountry,
        ]
    }
}


Shouldn't you be decoding BeneficiaryAddress as [String: AnyObject] and then converting it into what you need it to be, the same way as you converted the Beneficiary?

Can you give me an example? I'm trying it but not having any luck. I'm not sure if I need to created a computed property instead of another class?

You already have an init that's suitable, init(json: [String: AnyObject]), in BeneficiaryAddress so why not use it? As said first cast to a dictionary and then use the init

@JoakimDanielson I feel like that is what Im trying after hearing both of your advice. Would you be able to show me what you mean?

let temp = json[JSONConstants.beneficiaryAddress] as? [String: AnyObject] and then if temp is not nil let beneficiaryAddress = BeneficiaryAddress(json: temp)

@joakimDanielson Is this supposed to go in the convenience init in the Beneficiary class?

@JesseRae – Yes.

Conceivably, if you’re going to go down this road, you can have Beneficiary.init(json:) avail itself of the BeneficiaryAddress(json:) initializer, e.g.:
class Beneficiary {    
    …
    
    ///Convenience Init used to create a Beneficiary object with a json object
    convenience init(json: [String: AnyObject]) {
        let beneficiaryLastName = …
        let beneficiaryFirstName = …
        let beneficiaryDesignationCode = …
        let beneficiaryType = …
        let beneficiarySSN = …
        let beneficiaryDOB = …
        let beneficiaryMiddleName = …
        let beneficiaryPhoneNumber = …
        let beneficiaryAddress = if let addressDictionary = json[JSONConstants.beneficiaryAddress] as? [String: AnyObject] {
            BeneficiaryAddress(json: addressDictionary)
        } else {
            BeneficiaryAddress(beneficiaryAddressOne: "Unavailable", beneficiaryAddressTwo: "Unavailable", beneficiaryCity: "Unavailable", beneficiaryZipCode: "Unavailable", beneficiaryStateCode: "Unavailable", beneficiaryCountry: "Unavailable")
        }
        
        self.init(beneficiaryLastName: beneficiaryLastName, beneficiaryFirstName: beneficiaryFirstName, beneficiaryDesignationCode: beneficiaryDesignationCode, beneficiaryType: beneficiaryType, beneficiarySSN: beneficiarySSN, beneficiaryDOB: beneficiaryDOB, beneficiaryMiddleName: beneficiaryMiddleName, beneficiaryPhoneNumber: beneficiaryPhoneNumber, beneficiaryAddress: beneficiaryAddress)
    }
    
    …
}

There are lots of variations on the theme, but hopefully this illustrates the idea.

This did the trick for my app thank you. Makes a lot more sense now. I knew I was right there but it didn't look right to me. I literally looked all over the internet for any examples and couldn't find any. Everyone uses codable which is understandable.
